# Submit button calls the javascript function even though the fields are empty and not followed the pattern

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to JavaScript. I have a form in an html file that has some text fields. When someone click the submit button, a JavaScript function is called to do some work (in this case, a simple alert). It works as I wanted, when I fill the text fields and click the submit button it calls the JavaScript function and the function shows an alert. However, the problem is, when a user clicks the submit button keeping some fields empty and/or not following the pattern of an email address, it calls the JavaScript function (even though HTML 5 has shown warnings in the form). I want the JavaScript function should only be called if there are no HTML warnings, I mean no empty fields and the user must follow the email pattern. Thank you for your help.
**HTML code:**

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
                     
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                            
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                            
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            
    <button id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" type="submit" class="button button-a button-big button-rouded">Send Message</button>

</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="alert.js"></script>
```

**Javascript Code (alert.js):**

```
function SubmitFormData() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    alert("SHOW SOMETHING HERE");
}
```

Comment: No where in your code do you look up a validation library.... uncear what you are expecting those data attributes to do since that has nothing to do with HTML5 validation. What library were you referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **required** attribute in the input and one more thing you can call the SubmitFormData() **onsubmit form** here's your modified code :

```js
function SubmitFormData() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var message = $("#message").val();
  alert("SHOW SOMETHING HERE");
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm" onsubmit="SubmitFormData();">

  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" required/>

  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" required/>

  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>

  <button id="submitFormData" type="submit" class="button button-a button-big button-rouded">Send Message</button>

</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the `required` attribute to your fields, [see](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: required has no effects.  As you can see, I have used data-rule. For name data-rule="minlen:4", for email data-rule="email", for message data-rule="required"

Comment: the `data-*` attribute don't have the same effect as `required`, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp

Comment: Let me try. Thanks for the help.

Comment: OP is calling a function on button click, it has no relevance to the form or other inputs and/or their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best working solution for what you want to achieve by using the
**form validation JS plugin**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<style>
form label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

form div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

label.error {
  display: inline;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form[id="second_form"]').validate({
  rules: {
    name: 'required',
    
    user_email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
    },
    message: {
      required: true,
      
    }
  },
  messages: {
    name: 'This field is required',
   
    user_email: 'Enter a valid email',
    message: 'This field is required' 
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Example 2:</h2>
<form id="second_form" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" name="user_email" id="user_email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
  </div>
   
  <div>
    <label for="message">message:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way was to provide an HTML only solution based on a form element's `required` attribute since the browser will take over the validation of required elements also by their element/control `type` ...

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm" action="https://stackoverflow.com/">

  <input
    required
    type="text" name="name" id="name"
    class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name"
  />                          
  <input
    required
    type="email" name="email" id="email"
    class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email"
  />                          
  <textarea
    required
    name="message" id="message"
    class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

  <button
    type="submit" id="submitFormData"
    class="button button-a button-big button-rouded">Send Message</button>

</form>
```

A generic custom validation is much more complex and labour-intensive ...

```js
function validateControValue(elm) {
  let isValid = true;

  const elmType = elm.type;
  if (elmType !== 'button' && elmType !== 'submit') {

    const $elm = $(elm);
    const isEmpty = ($elm.val().trim() === '');

    if (isEmpty) {
      $elm.val('');
      $elm.addClass('validation-error');
    } else {
      $elm.removeClass('validation-error');
    }
    // non empty is valid, empty is invalid.
    isValid = !isEmpty; 
  }
  return isValid;
}

function handleValidFormSubmit(/* evt */) {
  const isValidSubmitData = Array
    .from(this.elements)
    .every(validateControValue);

  return isValidSubmitData;
}


function main() {
  $('#myForm').on('submit', handleValidFormSubmit)
}
$(document)
  .ready(main);
```

```css
.validation-error {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm" action="https://stackoverflow.com/">

  <input
    type="text" name="name" id="name"
    class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name"
  />                          
  <input
    type="email" name="email" id="email"
    class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email"
  />                          
  <textarea
    name="message" id="message"
    class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

  <button
    type="submit" id="submitFormData"
    class="button button-a button-big button-rouded">Send Message</button>

</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="alert.js"></script> //-->
```